# Logical-Tunnel Interface Juniper MX 480 doesn't "work"

Tags: routing, ipv4, juniper, vrf, juniper-mx

I have configured a logical tunnel between my master-routing-instance and a additional routing-instance. 
I tested the same config (except IP addresses) on my lab-system and on one of our other core-routers => Working!
But on this router, it doesn't work and I can't see the differences.

I have configured the tunnel-services for this fpc (fpc 0, pic 3) like this:

```
fpc 0 {
    pic 3 {
        tunnel-services {
            bandwidth 1g;
        }
    }
    sampling-instance sampling0;
}
```

And the routing-instance like this:
`instance-type virtual-router;
interface lt-0/3/10.10;
routing-options {
    static {
        route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop X.X.X.165;
    }
}`

And the lt-interface like this:
`show configuration interfaces lt-0/3/10 
unit 10 {
    encapsulation ethernet;
    peer-unit 11;
    family inet {
        address X.X.X.166/30;
    }
}
unit 11 {
    encapsulation ethernet;
    peer-unit 10;
    family inet {
        address X.X.X.165/30;
    }
}`

Now I expected to be able to ping from the routing-instance into my master-instance like this:`ping X.X.X.165 routing-instance RI`

But it isn't working.

Has anybody a clue?

P.S.: When I ping from master to routing-instance, the output-bytes counter of the lt-end in the routing-instance increase, what means that the routing-instance replies with echo-reply-packets. But the input-counter of the lt-end in the master instance doesn't receive them as the input counter does not count incoming packets....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add "show interfaces terse lt-*"?  Did you try it when things weren't in the routing instance?  It shouldn't matter, but it's just a way to rule out other config issues.